# How to generate a map in java 8 from a list in hibernate single table strategy for the below scenario

Tags: java, hibernate, single-table-inheritance

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PLAYER")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
          name="TEAM", 
          discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING
          )
public abstract class Player{
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_gen", sequenceName = "CONSTANTS_SEQ")
    protected long id;
    @Column(name="NAME")
    protected String name;
    @Column(name="YEAR")
    protected int year; 
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "SUNRISERS")
public class SunRisersPlayer extends Player{

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "KNIGHT_RIDERS")
public class KnightRidersPlayer extends Player{

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "DARE_DEVILS")
public class DareDevilsPlayer extends Player{
```

}

Here, I am trying to fetch all team players at once

```
public interface PlayerDao extends CrudRepository<Player, Long>{

    List<Player> findAll();
}
```

Sample PLAYER Table Data is

```
ID      name        year    team
1000    gilchrist   2015    SUNRISERS
1001    Yuvraj      2015    SUNRISERS
1002    Ghambir     2015    KNIGHT_RIDERS
1004    Pathan      2015    KNIGHT_RIDERS
1006    Umesh       2015    KNIGHT_RIDERS
1007    Zaheer      2015    DARE_DEVILS
1008    Venu        2015    DARE_DEVILS
```

Once I get the complete list, how to prepare a Map in Java 8 with the key as Team name and value as a list of players corresponding to that team?

Comment: Just don't use inheritance. Use a single TeamPlayer entity (use the singular form, BTW, not the plural form), and add a field named team to this entity.

Comment: Thanks, changed it to singular form, I was trying to use a single table inheritance example in this case.

Comment: Why use inheritance if the subclasses don't have any additional field, nor any different behavior?

Comment: I was trying to use hibernate features. I thought this would fit in this place. So, In which scenarios we can use this inheritance mapping?

Comment: When inheritance makes sense, i.e. when you have two entities, with an is-a association, and the sub-entity does things differently from the base one and has additional persistent properties.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use groupBy to get the complete list as shown below

Defined a transient variable in Player entity to get the team name

```
@Transient
public String getName(){
    DiscriminatorValue val = this.getClass().getAnnotation( DiscriminatorValue.class );
    return val == null ? null : StringUtils.remove(WordUtils.capitalizeFully(val.value(), '_'), "_");
}
```

By using team Name, I am grouping by as shown below to get the players for each team (`Map<String, List<Player>>`)

```
List<Player> players = playerDaoImpl.findAll();
Map<String, List<Player>> playersPerTeam= players.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Player::getName));
```